# Annihilation in free vacuum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, antimatter

I remember expositions on Feynman diagrams (like Flip Tanedo's https://www.quantumdiaries.org/2010/02/14/lets-draw-feynman-diagams/) and others representing electron-positron anihilation with emission of a gamma (with time running from left to right) as 'similar' to an electron being scattered by a gamma (with time running from bottom to top). This relates matter-antimatter to time reversal in some way.
Nice.
But I was shocked to learn recently that electron-positron anihilation with emission of a gamma does not conserve both energy and momentum. You can't convert a zero rest mass boson into two fermions without getting rid of the surplus momentum somehow.

Question 1 : that must have been evident to Feynman too, and to all those who used his diagrams. What am I missing  here?

Question 2 : Big-Bang matter surplus over anti matter, what does the above imply for the 'mass anihilation' concept? Does it require multi-particle interactions to work?

Comment: Concerning yor first question, most time one doesn't explicitly draw the other involved particles, e.g. the atomic nucleus balancing the momentum/energy conservation.

Comment: Feynman understood  conservation of energy and momentum quite well. You are simply misunderstanding what a Feynman diagram is and does. It amounts to a precise mathematical expression in covariant perturbation theory and not a  twisted scenario of absurdities.

Comment: @CosmasZachos : I'm not schooled in the subtle science and exact art of QED, so I rely on popularized blogs. They are somewhat twisted but rarely absurd. 'Outreach'?

Comment: You can't have "an electron being scattered by a gamma" (i.e., emitting *or* absorbing a photon, $e^- \leftrightarrow e^- + \gamma$) with real particles either. In the CM frame, you would have just an electron at rest, versus a moving electron and a photon, which could not conserve energy. Pointing this out in case it was not already clear, since the question notes two interpretations of the vertex but focuses only on the impossibility of a "real" vertex in the $e^+ + e^- \leftrightarrow \gamma$ case.

Comment: Just as annihilation requires two photons, the scattering case requires an incoming photon *and* an outgoing photon ($e^- + \gamma \to e^- + \gamma$), known as Compton scattering, described by a crossed version of the same two-vertex diagram in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For electron-positron emission, two photons are always involved so that momentum can be conserved. One of these, of course, comes from the $e^+e^-\gamma$ vertex, while the other can be thought of as coming from *initial-state radiation* before the vertex.

If the electron emits initial-state radiation, the Feynman diagram looks like this (time is the horizontal axis):

[image]

On the other hand, if the positron emits initial-state radiation, the Feynman diagram looks like this:

[image]

Since either one of these cases can happen in a general electron-positron annihilation, we typically write the Feynman diagram for the annihilation without specifying a particular time-ordering for the emission of the photons:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I take away that only the 2 initial and the 2 final states need to obay energy and momentum conservation simultaneously. The middle state can be 'virtual' and 'illegal' for a short while. So, it's a 4-body interaction after all.

Comment: @WouterM. It is indeed a 4-body interaction (a $2\to 2$ interaction, to be precise). But it's important to note that energy and momentum are still conserved at each vertex. A virtual particle still has to conserve energy and momentum; it just doesn't have to have the correct mass. As for it being "illegal", that's not true either. If you look carefully at what happens in each of the two time-orderings as you change reference frames, you'll see that there is no "rest frame" for the intermediate particle, no frame in which both time-orderings will give you an intermediate particle at rest.